# Bash - Split dir string

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I got the following string: '/transfer/IN/**name**/test.txt'

Now I'm trying to split this for the string **name**, cause I need it for further operations.

How can I split this correctly?

I've tried with **cut** (would **sed** be better?), but I'm not able to find the right approach.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help too:

```
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' <<<"/a/b/c/d"
```

And it outputs:

```
c
```

If you like using sed:

```
sed 's#/[^/]*$##;s#.*/##' <<<"/a/b/c/d"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the proper tools `dirname` and `basename` chained together:

```
echo $(basename $(dirname /transfer/IN/name/test.txt))
```

- `dirname` => `/transfer/IN/name`
- `basename` => `name`

`sed` solution looks more complex BTW:

```
 sed -e "s#.*/\([^/]*\)/[^/]*#\1#" -e "s#/.*##" <<< name/test.txt
```

(2 expressions to handle the full relative case `name/test.txt`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/transfer/IN/name/test.txt
path1=${path%/*}           # Remove everything from the last /.
path1=${path1##*/}         # Remove everything up to the last /.
echo "$path1"
```